# Найти пунктуационную ошибку

Tags: пунктуация

К соседке бабушка относилась плохо за то, что та суёт нос туда, куда ей не следует и судит о том, чего не понимает. Подскажите пожалуйста, где в этом предложении пунктуационная ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока вижу отсутствующую запятую:

К соседке бабушка относилась плохо за то, что та суёт нос туда, **куда ей не следует,** и судит о том, чего не понимает.

Без запятой тут никак - надо закрыть оборот "куда ей не следует".
Этого достаточно?

Я бы еще здесь не полагался на умолчание и писал бы полностью: "куда ей **его совать** не следует" Но это уже скорее стилистика, чем синтаксис.

Answer (score 1):

Пунктуационную вижу, синтаксическую - нет.

К соседке бабушка относилась плохо за то, что та суёт нос туда, куда ей не следует**,** и судит о том, чего не понимает. Куда ей не следует - придаточное места, обособляется с двух сторон.

Comment: А может быть, лучше сказать "К соседке бабушка относится плохо, потому что та..." или все в прошедшем времени

Answer (score 1):

В исходном предложении не хватает запятой после "следует", но такое впечатление, что оно получено путём распространения устойчивого оборота, не требующего запятых:

К соседке бабушка относилась плохо за то, что та суёт нос куда не следует и судит о том, чего не понимает.

Answer (score 1):

> К соседке бабушка относилась плохо за то

Здесь больше напрашивается "потому", а не "за то"

> Подскажите пожалуйста, где в этом предложении пунктуационная ошибка.

А здесь не хватает запятой перед словом "пожалуйста".